# Could not upload file in mapped drive in VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, networking, file-upload

I have tried several times to upload file remotely in network mapped drive but it raising exception

**Could not find a part of the path 'X:\test\testing.wav'.**

I walk over internet /blog/ microsoft help site. has changed some configuration for get the solution. Finally i am failed.

So, Actually any one around there, who could give me the exact solution??

Regards,
Nazmul Hasan

Comment: How are we supposed to find a problem in code we can't see?

Comment: @KendallFrey - It was simple uploading code. just i am using mapped drive to save uploaded file.

Comment: i used shared drive but it asking for authentication.

Comment: Could it have something to do with the " in your filepath?

Comment: @GeorgeK - Its working fine, when i am uploading in local drive. also working in network drive when i am running from development server. but if i tried with published code then failed. :(

Comment: If you don't think the problem is with your code, then serverfault or superuser might be a better place to ask.

Comment: @KendallFrey - Could you please make it more clear it to me. I think i have no problem with code.

Comment: Hi ALL, I have got the solution. Created a application pool and defied a user for pool which user has full control in shared folder and using UNC path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the solution. Created a application pool and defined a user for pool which user has full control in shared folder and using UNC path

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to say that you cannot use " in a filename. It might be a simple typo but you cannot use a " in a filename

Answer (score 0):

Since this works on one machine and not another, you are facing one of two problems.

1. Permissions on the production box are different than the development/staging box. Verify the user account that hosts your application has read/write access to the target path.
2. Your production box cannot see the file on that path. This would most likely be an issue with drive mapping. Instead of pointing to "x" point to \server\share\.